# Struggling with deployment of JNI library dependency in Tomcat

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, java-native-interface, war

Here's my setup at the moment:

- Web app (deployed as a .war to Tomcat) that I am adding functionality that uses a JNI wrapper library to interface with a native library.
- The wrapper library ssc.dll/so
- The wrapped library SSCAPIJNI.dll/so
- Both libraries are embedded in a jar in the war

  - Within the war they are at the path /lib/linux/*.so and /lib/windows/*.dll
- Using [this helper code](http://pastebin.com/WJJiEtPx) in [this manner](http://pastebin.com/Wm54W6z3) the application successfully extracts, loads, and calls into the native code both in my Windows dev environment and on our linux based continuous integration server.

  - I can, through Eclipse, run and use the application in my local dev environment
  - The CI successfully runs tests on the code using ant and junit

However, when I deploy the war to my QA server I get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

Because the wrapper lib and wrapped lib are separate it is not enough to get the java library search path correct, the OS's native library search path needs to see the wrapped library when loading the wrapper library, which seems to be where the failure occurs. I do not have the option of compiling the two together.

Although I've been stumbling through this with some success, this current obstacle is one I want to fix "the right way", as such my question is this:

What is a correct and robust way to deploy a JNI library that depends on a second native library to Tomcat in such a way that Tomcat can see the wrapper lib which in turn can see the wrapped lib?

Comment: Which exact version of Tomcat?